# Create 1D numpy arrays from 2D array of connectivities

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of connectivities for outer/boundary edges of tri mesh shown below:

[image: 2d_connectivity]

arranged like this:

```py
edges = \
[[ 1  0]
 [10 11]
 [ 2  1]
 [11 12]
 [ 3  2]
 [12 13]
 [ 4  3]
 [13 14]
 [ 5  4]
 [14 15]
 [ 6  5]
 [15 16]
 [ 7  6]
 [16 17]
 [ 8  7]
 [17 18]
 [ 9  8]
 [18 19]
 [ 0  9]
 [19 10]]
```

I want to create 2 arrays containing connectivity of loops (inner and outer circles) like this

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
b = [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

The loops just happen to have continuous numbering in this case but in general this is not the case and I can have more than 2 loops. In general the 2D edge connectivity can have completely random numbering. My `O(n^2)` algorithm that picks one point on the loop and finds the next one is too slow. What is an optimal way to extract multiple loop information from 2D connectivity?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your graph is undirected. Is it true? The main issue is that the loops are highly dependent of the (planar) representation of your graph. In fact the notion of "circle" is subjective since nodes are not associated to a given fixed location. Why `[0, 10, 11, 1]` would not work? Why not `[0, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Comment: They are undirected indeed and in fact sense od direction does not matter to my workflow as long as loops have continuous travesal (start and end). I want to extract the graph connectivity (travesals) for outer loops only. `[0 10]` is inner edge which is not what I want. `[8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]` however will work in that, the starting point of the loop and how it is travesed is also irrelevant to me.